# Add separator to elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This html:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class='link-separated'>foo</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  <a class='link-separated'>foo</a>
  <a class='link-separated'>bar</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class='link-separated'>foo</a>
    <a class='link-separated'>bar</a>
    <a class='link-separated'>xyz</a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

will produce:

```
foo
foo bar
foo bar xyz
```

What I want to get is:

```
foo
foo | bar
foo | bar | xyz
```

I've managed something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/61yfcnjh/ but this solution is weird - `.link-separated` is used twice. How can it be done better?

Comment: Use the pseudo `::after` element: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/tkogjd50/

Comment: an alternative to @ChrisG its to use  `.link-separated + .link-separated:before{content: " | ";}` as a single rule

Comment: @ChrisG 1 thing is problematic - separator is a part of hyperlink: https://jsfiddle.net/gjdn5ke3/. Is there a way of fixing that?

Comment: In your fiddle you don't need the first .link-separated updated: https://jsfiddle.net/wths6Lz3/ and using `:last-child` you don't need the outer loop https://jsfiddle.net/wths6Lz3/1/

Comment: Shorter jquery code: `$(".link-separated+.link-separated").before(" | ")` https://jsfiddle.net/wths6Lz3/2/

Comment: True, that means you need additional elements, so your solution seems fine in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to further simplify it:

```js
$("td a.link-separated:not(:last-child)").after(" | ");
```

Try it:

```js
$("td a.link-separated:not(:last-child)").after(" | ");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class='link-separated'>foo</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class='link-separated'>foo</a>
      <a href="#" class='link-separated'>bar</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class='link-separated'>foo</a>
      <a href="#" class='link-separated'>bar</a>
      <a href="#" class='link-separated'>xyz</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```